# Why does my font size in Message Preview randomly shrink?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Normally in my Message Preview in Otulook, the Recipient's Name (in green) is way bigger than the Subject Title and Lien preview (in red).

[image]

But sometimes when I open Outlook, the Recipient's Name dwindles and is not much bigger than the other two. I don't know why, and I didn't change any settings.

[image]

Comment: You are showing two different views I think Outlook. Go to the View tab and look at what may be different between the two layouts.

Comment: This may be a difference between different view. Please click View to rest your view or always use a same view.

Comment: @music2myear Can you pls be more specific? What in the "View tab" do I need to change?

Comment: @Aidan  Can you pls be more specific? What in the "View tab" do I need to change?

Comment: You are not showing the same screens so it's impossible to see the difference. Replace your second screenshot with one that is the same as the first, but showing the problem.

Comment: I suggest you accept the answer you found most useful so it appears at the top, for the benefit of the community.

Answer (score 1):

You are working in two different mail accounts that might have different views set up.

Just open all your mail accounts and press (and confirm the prompt that follows) the 'Reset View' under the 'View' tab.

And/or change your Views to eg. Compact.

Answer (score 0):

The way to change the font size is with ([source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/change-font-size-of-sender-name/e20605fd-4407-46d8-97e2-3775600be56f?tab=AllReplies#tabs), e.g.):
`View`-> `View Settings` -> `Conditional Formatting...` -> `Add` -> Set the name (e.g., Standard font size) -> `Font...` -> Set font size -> `Ok` -> `Ok` -> `Ok`.

You are likely using different views for each case you show, one of them with such a rule.
You can change this with `View` -> `Change view` ...
In the worst case, you may try `Reset view` (as in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1539235/245595)), but this option gives you something to try first.

Even if you do not find the different views (so, technically, I would not be answering your question, **Why...?**) you may try applying the method above, to see if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your first screenshot, the "Message Preview" as it is called has the sender in a large font, the subject below that in a smaller but still crisp font, then the multiple lines of the body below that in a slightly lighter font than the subject line.
This is the default setup for the "Compact" view.

Sometimes an update or something can change the view settings, which is what has happened in your second screenshot. To fix it, follow these steps:

1. Click View
   [image: Step 1 Screenshot]
2. Click Change View
3. Ensure Compact is selected. Then click Manage Views...
   [image: Step 3 Screenshot]
4. Highlight the Compact line, click Reset, then click Apply View
   [image: Step 4 Screenshot]
5. (Optional) To apply to all other folders, go back here and click Apply Current View to Other Mail Folders...
   [image: Step 5 Screenshot]

Comment: I'm not sure why my screenshots are linked as imgur links. I could have sworn you could paste images directly from the clipboard.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277844/must-we-use-imgur-for-images